# mongoose syntax error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Estou a tentar criar uma aplicação usando express.js e mongodb, quando tento correr o servidor aparece esse erro de syntax. O erro que aparece refere-se a um documento só com zeros(Ex: `0000 0000 0000 0000`), sou um noob na matéria.

```
D:\teste de apps\mean\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\rea  
d_preference.js:1                                                         
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {             
                                                              ^           
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL                                     
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                   
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                     
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                           
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)                                  
    at require (module.js:380:17)                                         
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\teste de apps\mean\node_modules\mongoose\l  
ib\utils.js:5:16)                                                         
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                   
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

//MEAN-APP/config/mongoose.js

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(){
    var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
    require('../app/models/user.server.model');
    return db;
};
```

//MEAN-APP/config/env/development.js

```
module.exports = {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-book',
    // Development configuration options
    // the sessionSecret string can be anything
    sessionSecret: 'developmentSessionSecret'
}
```

//MEAN-APP/server.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var mongoose = require('./config/mongoose');
var express = require('./config/express');

var db = mongoose();
var app = express();

app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app;

console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

//MEAN-APP/config/express.js

```
var session     = require('express-session'),
    config      = require('./config'),
    express     = require('express'),
    morgan      = require('morgan'),
   compress     = require('compression'),
 bodyParser     = require('body-parser'),
 methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    mongoose    = require('mongoose');

module.exports= function(){
    var app = express();
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV ==='production'){
        app.use(compress());
    }
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended : true
    }));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());

    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: config.sessionSecret
    }));

    app.set('views', './app/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);

    app.use(express.static('./public'));

    return app;
}
```

Comment: Tens de juntar mais código e explicar o que está a acontecer. Colocar aqui somente o erro não dá margem para ajudar. E por favor escreve em Português. Esse parentesis no inicio não está a mais? ou tens uma IIFE com `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ...})()`?

Comment: estou a tentar criar uma aplicação usando express.js e mongodb, quando tento correr o servidor aparece esse erro de syntax. O erro que aparece refere-se a um documento só com zeros(Ex: 0000 0000 0000 0000), sou um noob na matéria.

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta para ir juntando detalhes. Quando surgiu o erro? mudaste alguma linha? podes colocar o código que estás a fazer?

Comment: O erro surgiu exactamente quando tentava ligar a base de dados com express

Comment: //mongoose.js                                               var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(){
 var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
 require('../app/models/user.server.model');
 return db;
};

Comment: Sérgio quando vou ver onde aparece o erro, abro o documento e é isto que aparece em '\mean\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\rea
d_preference.js:1': 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 eu não faço a minima ideia onde essa IIFE se encontra.